# Discrete math and Sets: Define a relation $R \subseteq \{0,1,2,3,4\} \times \{0,1,2,3,4\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am stuck on the very bottom problem. I have defined k1-9 and r1-9. However I do not understand what I am being asked to find where it says {$(r_{9-k}, r_k)$}.

> Define a relation $R \subseteq \{0,1,2,3,4\} \times \{0,1,2,3,4\} =: \mathcal U$ as follows:
>
> Compute $R$ on the facing page, and write the answer below
>   $$
> R := \bigcup_{k \in 1,\dots,8}\{(r_{9-k},r_k)\}\\
> = \hspace{2.75 cm}
> $$

[image: Picture of the problem]

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that $k\in1..8$ is some locally defined shorthand for $k\in\{1,\ldots,8\}$, it means
$$ \begin{align}R&=\bigcup_{k\in\{1,\ldots,8\}}\{(r_{9-k},r_k)\}\\&=\{(r_{9-1},r_1)\}\cup\{(r_{9-2},r_2)\}\cup\ldots\cup\{(r_{9-8},r_8)\}\\
&=\{(r_8,r_1)\}\cup\{(r_7,r_2)\}\cup\ldots\cup\{(r_1,r_8)\}\\
&=\{(r_8,r_1),(r_7,r_2),\ldots,(r_1,r_8)\}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

The notation of the bottom problem is a union of sets. If I have sets $X_1,\dotsc, X_k$, then
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^k X_i = \{x: x\in X_i\text{ for some $i$ between $1$ and $k$}\}.$$

The sets we're taking the union of in the case of the problem are one-point sets (also called "singletons"). Thus we just collect all of the points in our singletons into one set. The notation $(r_{9-k}, r_k)$ refers to a coordinate pair (note that $R$ is a subset of the product of two sets!). Letting $k=1,2\dotsc, 8$ and listing out the points, we find that the entire union is
$$\{(r_8,r_1), (r_7,r_2),(r_6,r_3),\dotsc, (r_2,r_7), (r_1, r_8)\}.$$